# When does tetrahedron's height contain the orthocenter of its base triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, solid-geometry

Suppose there is a tetrahedron $SABC$ with $S$ being its apex, and $H$ being the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$. When is the line $SH$ perpendicular to the plane $ABC$ except for the case of $SABC$ being a right tetrahedron?

I'd like to know if there are any other cases and how do you find these. Internet gave me no visible information of that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Orthocentric tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_tetrahedron)

Comment: @JeanMarie by height $SH$ of the tetrahedron I clearly meant the distance from the apex $S$ to the plane $ABC$. Orthocentric tetrahedrons are just one case where bases of heights for all edges are located in the orthocenter. I'm talking about the cases when at least one edge has the base of the tetrahedron's height equal to the orthocenter of the triangle.

Comment: I would try the construction starting with the base triangle and taking a perpendicular from $H$. You can take any base triangle and $S$ at any height. You probably get a condition from taking the scalar product of $SH$ with any two of the altitudes of the triangle (perpendiculars give scalar product zero) - not sure how useable that turns out to be.

Comment: Otherwise said, you would like a necessary and sufficient condition (a characteristic property) for a tetrahedron to have this property ? I have some doubts that there is a different characterization...

Comment: @JeanMarie Exactly that!